# find 2-3 terms of power expansion of parameter $\mu$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, cauchy-problem

I have the equation:

$$xy' = \mu x^2 + \ln y \quad y(1)=1$$

I am given the polynomial:

$$y(x,\mu) = y_0(x)+\mu y_1(x) + \mu^2 y_2(x) \ldots$$

I honestly do not know how to approach this topic at all, (which topic should I study?). Please advice how to proceed. The *only* idea I had is to substitute $y(x,\mu )$ into the equation, but then what?

Comment: this is perturbation theory, try and use the ODE to equate coefficients

Comment: check this https://www.ucl.ac.uk/~ucahhwi/LTCC/section2-3-perturb-regular.pdf